# Kendo UI for MVC Grid How do I hide the ID column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

I would like to hide the ID column of a Kendo grid but still be able to reference it for other actions. I tried making the Width = 0 but that only makes it really wide.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("LineItems")
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.ID).Width(1);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Ui).Width(20);
                columns.Bound(o => o.QtyOrdered).Width(20);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Nomenclature).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(o => o.QtyShipped).Width(140);
                columns.Bound(o => o.QtyReceived).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Hazmat).Width(50);

            })
```

**Edit on June 26**

OK I was able to get a reasonable solution based on a post from the Kendo forum. As long as the ID is defined in the datasource, the column does not have to be defined in the grid. You still have access to the ID value. I wrote a quick snippet to prove it and it returns the ID without the ID column in the grid.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btn").on("click", function () {

          var grid = $("#LineItems").data("kendoGrid");
          var data = grid.dataSource.data();
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
              alert(item.ID);
           });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you take a look at this post in there forums http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/hide-columns-in-grid-kendo.aspx

Comment: You can reference the ID column without making it a column. As long as the ID column is defined in the data source model, it does not need to be defined in the columns setup.

Comment: @Daniel, you are correct, I somehow missed your comment until after I edited my post with the same solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden columns are supported since the Q2 2012 release. You can now use the `Hidden()` setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the column hidden via the Hidden() method. Is this okey for you?

Comment: .Hidden() is not an option with the Kendo Grid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the current version its not supported, they do have a page where you can vote to get this feature added to Kendo. They may have started working on it since the status does say 'started' about 13 hours ago.

http://kendo.uservoice.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2804580-ability-to-show-hide-columns-in-grid

In the meantime it looks like some users might have some suggestions in this post by setting the style of that column to `display:none`
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/hide-columns-in-grid-kendo.aspx