# Kendo UI Grid - Hide/Unhide of column in MVC3

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

My case is a search window with around 20 properties, in which the user can choose to specify search criteria. Each property has a corresponding checkbox which toggles if the prop is included in the search result or not. The search result is then displayed in a kendo grid.

Simplified code which should illustrate the issue (kendo ui complete ver. 2012.2.710):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="fnShowHide(1);" name="showSearchColumn" id="checkShowField1"  />                                

<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="kendoGridTest"></div>
</div>

<script>
function fnShowHide( iCol )
{
   $('#kendoGridTest').data("kendoGrid").options.columns[iCol].hidden = false;
   $('#kendoGridTest').data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}
</script>
```

The MVC3-controller method returns data from search is of type JsonResult (given as `jsonResultSearchResult` below):

```
$('#kendoGridTest').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: jsonResultSearchResult,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                FirstName: { type: "string" },
                LastName: { type: "string" },
                Address: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        width: 90,
        title: "First name"
    },
        {
            field: "LastName",
            width: 120,
            hidden: true,
            title: "Last name"
        },
        {
            field: "Address",
            width: 140,
            title: "Adr"
        }
    ]
});
```

After performing a search, the grid fills with the right data and `LastName` is indeed hidden. But if the user now checks the `checkShowField1` control, I would like the grid to refresh with all three cols visible. It does not. `fnShowHide()` does not do the job.

I must admit I was looking for anything of a type of Columns collection in a QuickWatch window while debugging in VS. The collection in `fnShowHide` contains the right data from when the grid was initialized, and I'm able to manipulate the `.hidden` property, but the grid still does not display the column.

I'm still a bit confused whether dynamic hide/show of cols *is* supported but [this accepted answer from a Telerik employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210989/kendo-ui-for-mvc-grid-how-do-i-hide-the-id-column) looked promising.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To hide a column on the client side with JavaScript you should use the **hideColumn()** and to show it you use the **showColumn()**. Both methods have several overloads - you either pass the index of the column or you pass the name of the field the column is bound to.
For example:

```
var grid = $('#GridID').data('kendoGrid');
grid.hideColumn(2);
//or show it
grid.showColumn("OrderDate") // lets say thats the field name of the same column
```

The post you linked shows how to Hide/Show column with the MVC Wrappers which is slightly different.

Comment: thks, if i want to show all column which hide then how can do it? i.e what is best way to do?

Comment: To show all the columns you can cycle through them 


for(var i=0;i<grid.columns.length;i++){ 
     grid.showColumn(i); 
}